# TypeScript support in modern browsers

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I've just read some advertisement information related to TypeScript and besides that I have no experience with this superset of JavaScript. So I have some basic questions:

1. What is the status of native TypeScript support by the modern browsers?
2. What are the positions of the major browser vendors for the future support of TypeScript natively?
3. What is the relation between TypeScript and [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) and does TypeScript provide much more features than ECMAScript 6?

Comment: Maybe the question could use some simplifying, though it's still clear that the core issue is that a simple google search won't (right now) return a single page with a list of browsers that support what versions of Typescript _natively_

Comment: The reason for why this question was closed does not make sense at all. It is a perfectly valid question which would help anyone attempting to learn typescript. For first timers its always confusing and generally a mis conception that TypeScript is evaluated and run in the browser since it is mentioned as a super script of javascript. Well, it is in a different sense so some of these questions help shed light on those building block details

Comment: @EmmanuelPonnudurai I’m an old timer and I found this question valid and relevant even 8yrs later

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Native support

Native support can be added quite easily e.g. https://github.com/basarat/typescript-script adds support for script tags (although this adds 6 MB of supporting JavaScript to a page). However there is a performance hit in compiling TypeScript to JavaScript and for the best performance it is best to precompile and execute the compiled JavaScript in the browsers.

Browser vendors have no plans to add native TypeScript support. The only native languages common across browsers are JavaScript and [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly). TypeScript can be transpiled to either and run in the browsers so its not a blocker.

## Not-native support

> What is the status of TypeScript support by the modern browsers?

TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, so it's supported by all browsers (even [Internet Explorer 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6)).

> What are the positions of the major browser vendors for the future support of TypeScript?

No work is needed on behalf of browser vendors.

> What is the relation between TypeScript and ECMAScript6 and does TypeScript provide much more features than ECMAScript6 ?

Yes, e.g., from future JavaScript versions, e.g., class fields and static properties in classes.

Comment: That's clearly mot what Artem meant. Support of TypeScript in browser means that you can directly use TypeScript in the pages that the browser loads.

Comment: Quite. No idea what the stack nerdlords have closed this question for, it's perfectly obvious what the OP is asking, and this answer doesn't provide the answer.

Comment: The question was "What is the status of NATIVE TypeScript support by the modern browsers"

Comment: `NATIVE` was added after I had answered. And was added by someone who is *not* the OP: https://imgur.com/a/haFrB

Comment: "TypeScript should not be run natively" Why not?
"Typescript compiles to JS so it's supported by all browsers" That does not answer the question.

Comment: So if you're only willing to spend your life pursuing mastery and maintaining fluency in either one or the other but not both, then, well, if you ever want to do anything in the js console, the native JavaScript is what you've got. (Unless you want to deal with 6MB of mystery padding between you and the browser while you're in the js console.) </snark>

Comment: This seems like an opinion piece more than an actual logical answer, why shouldn't TypeScript be supported natively?

Comment: @Russell Thanks, I've removed my opinion and added reasons + industry directions.

Comment: 404 not found  .

Answer (score 16):

Trying to design a web browser that could natively support more than one language at a time is exactly what Google tried to do with [Dart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dart_%28programming_language%29). There was a Dart engine planned for Chrome, but this ended up being too big a task with very little benefit aside from "just not using JavaScript".

I suspect supporting TypeScript natively would be an equally daunting task. Probably better to just improve upon ECMAScript and add in a few TypeScript  ideas where they make sense. I do love TypeScript though.

Comment: I don't think it would be _equally_ daunting. It seems like TS support could be achieved by  adding on to the existing JS parser to parse the language, then simply strip out the TS-specific syntax, and run the resulting code on V8, which is possible since TS is a superset of JS. Dart is a completely different language requiring its own AST and VM.

Comment: @brandon-duffany, It is not possible to "strip out" TypeScript code to plain JavaScript. You need an actual full-fledged TS compiler to convert all TS features like Generics, Union Types, Intersection types etc to equivalent JS code; unfortunately they cannot just be "stripped out". It's true that TS is a superset of JS, what that means is that any valid JS is TS, but that does not neccessarily mean that TS can be easily converted back to JS by deleting type annotations and stuff.

Comment: I don't mean that it has to implement any kind of runtime type checking. After all, TS isn't type checked at runtime either. For example, when the browser sees `type Foo = string | int`, it could just say "oh this is a type declaration. Let's ignore it.". Then when it sees `let foo: Foo = 1`, it could choose to ignore the `: Foo` part. Perfectly valid JS.

It's very different from Dart, because Dart is actually type checked at runtime.

Comment: >  simply strip out the TS-specific syntax

  
I think this will defeat the performance benefits of using TS in the browser. I assume that the JS engine could be further sped up by using actual types. Some performance enhancements do just this - infer types.
  
> It is not possible to "strip out" TypeScript code to plain JavaScript
  
But you can run JS with a TS native runtime (which doesn't exist atm).

Comment: You don't need a full-fledged TS compiler. Things like Webpack do exactly what @Brandon is talking about when they compile TS – they convert a few things (enums for example need to be converted to an object), but otherwise they literally just strip out all type information and call it a day. You don't need to convert Generics / Union / etc because types aren't needed at runtime.

Comment: @arminrosu > "I think this will defeat the performance benefits of using TS in the browser." -- the main benefit is not performance, it's convenience. Developers want to be able to run TypeScript directly in the browser without needing an intermediate compiler. Having to compile TS -> JS is a pain.

Answer (score 7):

TypeScript cannot be run or understood in any browser. So, TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript (which browsers can understand). TypeScript can use all [ECMAScript 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) features and during the compilation they will be converted to *target* compile options like [ES5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition).

Answer (score 4):

Currently it won't work, but it's an interesting topic though. It would be good to know if at some point ECMAScript is going to support interfaces, types and other things. Especially, I can notice that ECMAScript actually slowly takes some parts from the TypeScript, e.g. enums.

If it would work, I'd rather see it as ECMAScript taking some stuff from TypeScript rather than natively supporting TypeScript itself.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's currently not supported and there are no plans to support TypeScript natively in the browser but there is a huge (in my opinion) problem with tooling in the frontend (JavaScript) ecosystem - there's too much of it. Bundling, module resolution, [transpiling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transpile#Verb), and more.

I think it makes development much slower, because there are a lot of issues with configurations, versions mismatch, compatibility and a lot of obscure issues (Stack Overflow and GitHub are full of such topics) that stem from the tooling, not implementing features.

I would call it a crisis, but it has been like this for a while and I know this is the way of doing things now.

I think there are a few things that need to happen.

1. We need to be able to use native [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) modules (import/export) in the browser. I know it's supported, but only a relative or URL imports work. I know there is work on "import maps" or whatever they are called.
2. It would be great if browsers (Chrome) can read TypeScript code. It doesn’t have to interpret or enforce any typing - essentially treat it like JavaScript with some additional nonsense that the browser just ignores. It could be just a "developer mode" in the browser but we would be able to achieve 0-transpiling during development.
3. Simplify eager resource loading (to avoid bundling)

Again, this is just for development benefit. I know a lot of these tools have their place in production builds, older browser support, etc.