# Succeeded in running the sample code in node.js ,but failed to run the modified code in a browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, asynchronous, browser

I ran the code sample given in the webpage

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/feature/storage/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples/javascript/basic.js

successfully in node.js, however, when I tried to run the code in browser after I followed the instructions given in the webpage

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/feature/storage/sdk/storage/storage-blob#javascript-bundle

and

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/feature/storage/sdk/storage/storage-blob#download-a-blob-and-convert-it-to-a-string-browsers

I got an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

I created a .js file with the same code in the code sample and changed some part of the code according to the instructions in order to run in Chrome. After I had done so I already got 5 errors in the editor such as

```
'types' can only be used in a .ts file.
```

```
'type arguments' can only be used in a .ts file.
```

However, I assume that might not be a problem if I run the code in Chrome. Therefore I continue to attach this .js file to the scipt tag in the .html file created in the same directory.

This is the .js code given in the sample:

```
/* 
 Setup: Enter your storage account name and shared key in main()
*/

const { BlobServiceClient, SharedKeyCredential } = require("../.."); // Change to "@azure/storage-blob" in your package

async function main() {
  // Enter your storage account name and shared key
  const account = "";
  const accountKey = "";

  // Use SharedKeyCredential with storage account and account key
  // SharedKeyCredential is only avaiable in Node.js runtime, not in browsers
  const sharedKeyCredential = new SharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);

  // ONLY AVAILABLE IN NODE.JS RUNTIME
  // DefaultAzureCredential will first look for Azure Active Directory (AAD)
  // client secret credentials in the following environment variables:
  //
  // - AZURE_TENANT_ID: The ID of your AAD tenant
  // - AZURE_CLIENT_ID: The ID of your AAD app registration (client)
  // - AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET: The client secret for your AAD app registration
  //
  // If those environment variables aren't found and your application is deployed
  // to an Azure VM or App Service instance, the managed service identity endpoint
  // will be used as a fallback authentication source.
  // const defaultAzureCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

  // Use TokenCredential with OAuth token
  // const tokenCredential = new RawTokenCredential("token");
  // tokenCredential.token = "renewedToken"; // Renew the token by updating token field of token credential

  // Use AnonymousCredential when url already includes a SAS signature
  // const anonymousCredential = new AnonymousCredential();

  // List containers
  const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
    // When using AnonymousCredential, following url should include a valid SAS or support public access
    `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
    sharedKeyCredential
  );

  let i = 1;
  for await (const container of blobServiceClient.listContainers()) {
    console.log(`Container ${i++}: ${container.name}`);
  }

  // Create a container
  const containerName = `newcontainer${new Date().getTime()}`;
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

  const createContainerResponse = await containerClient.create();
  console.log(`Create container ${containerName} successfully`, createContainerResponse.requestId);

  // Create a blob
  const content = "hello";
  const blobName = "newblob" + new Date().getTime();
  const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);
  const blockBlobClient = blobClient.getBlockBlobClient();
  const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(content, content.length);
  console.log(`Upload block blob ${blobName} successfully`, uploadBlobResponse.requestId);

  // List blobs
  i = 1;
  for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
    console.log(`Blob ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
  }

  // Get blob content from position 0 to the end
  // In Node.js, get downloaded data by accessing downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody
  // In browsers, get downloaded data by accessing downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody
  const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blobClient.download(0);
  console.log(
    "Downloaded blob content",
    await streamToString(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody)
  );

  // Delete container
  await containerClient.delete();

  console.log("deleted container");
}

// A helper method used to read a Node.js readable stream into string
async function streamToString(readableStream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
      chunks.push(data.toString());
    });
    readableStream.on("end", () => {
      resolve(chunks.join(""));
    });
    readableStream.on("error", reject);
  });
}

// An async method returns a Promise object, which is compatible with then().catch() coding style.
main()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully executed sample.");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

This is the .js file I created in order to run in Chrome:

```
/* 
 Setup: Enter your storage account name and shared key in main()
*/

const { BlobServiceClient, SharedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/storage-blob"); // Change to "@azure/storage-blob" in your package

async function main() {
  // Enter your storage account name and shared key
  const account = "";
  const accountKey = "";

  // Use SharedKeyCredential with storage account and account key
  // SharedKeyCredential is only avaiable in Node.js runtime, not in browsers
  const sharedKeyCredential = new SharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);

  // ONLY AVAILABLE IN NODE.JS RUNTIME
  // DefaultAzureCredential will first look for Azure Active Directory (AAD)
  // client secret credentials in the following environment variables:
  //
  // - AZURE_TENANT_ID: The ID of your AAD tenant
  // - AZURE_CLIENT_ID: The ID of your AAD app registration (client)
  // - AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET: The client secret for your AAD app registration
  //
  // If those environment variables aren't found and your application is deployed
  // to an Azure VM or App Service instance, the managed service identity endpoint
  // will be used as a fallback authentication source.
  // const defaultAzureCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

  // Use TokenCredential with OAuth token
  // const tokenCredential = new RawTokenCredential("token");
  // tokenCredential.token = "renewedToken"; // Renew the token by updating token field of token credential

  // Use AnonymousCredential when url already includes a SAS signature
  // const anonymousCredential = new AnonymousCredential();

  // List containers
  const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
    // When using AnonymousCredential, following url should include a valid SAS or support public access
    `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
    sharedKeyCredential
  );

  let i = 1;
  for await (const container of blobServiceClient.listContainers()) {
    console.log(`Container ${i++}: ${container.name}`);
  }

  // Create a container
  const containerName = `newcontainer${new Date().getTime()}`;
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

  const createContainerResponse = await containerClient.create();
  console.log(`Create container ${containerName} successfully`, createContainerResponse.requestId);

  // Create a blob
  const content = "hello";
  const blobName = "newblob" + new Date().getTime();
  const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);
  const blockBlobClient = blobClient.getBlockBlobClient();
  const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(content, content.length);
  console.log(`Upload block blob ${blobName} successfully`, uploadBlobResponse.requestId);

  // List blobs
  i = 1;
  for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
    console.log(`Blob ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
  }

 // Get blob content from position 0 to the end
  // In browsers, get downloaded data by accessing downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody
  const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blobClient.download(0);
  console.log(
    "Downloaded blob content",
    await blobToString(downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody)
  );

  // Delete container
  await containerClient.delete();

  console.log("deleted container");
}

// [Browsers only] A helper method used to convert a browser Blob into string.
export async function blobToString(blob: Blob): Promise<string> {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      fileReader.onloadend = (ev: any) => {
        resolve(ev.target!.result);
      };
      fileReader.onerror = reject;
      fileReader.readAsText(blob);
    });
  }

// An async method returns a Promise object, which is compatible with then().catch() coding style.
main()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully executed sample.");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

This is the code I typed in the .html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="azure-storage-blob.min.js"></script>
        <script src="browsertest.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

I got this error in the console:

```
browsertest.js:84 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

but I got the following error in the editor:

```
'types' can only be used in a .ts file.
```

```
'type arguments' can only be used in a .ts file.
```

So I wonder which one is the real problem?

Should I put the code given in the webpage

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/feature/storage/sdk/storage/storage-blob#download-a-blob-and-convert-it-to-a-string-browsers

in a .ts file and compile them into javascript code?

Comment: The link to samples code is to feature/storage branch and now out-of-date. Here's the latest link https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob#download-a-blob-and-convert-it-to-a-string-browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **blobToString** function declaration, and **return** statement contain the TypeScript notation, which is not supported natively by browsers. In this case you need either compile your js code into "common" javascript which is supported by browsers (ES5).

see related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22888682/3419751)

Comment: I am sorry if I got this wrong, but do you literally mean that since some of the code in my modified .js file contain TypeScript notation therefore I need to used the method provided in the webpage 
https://github.com/basarat/typescript-script
to compile the whole file into .js file in order to run my modified code in browser?

Comment: Yes. That will work for your tests/learning/PoC etc. If you will build an app (frontend)  which has TypeScript within a code then you may need some more advanced tools like gulp, webpack to help you to do compilation and build the final JS file(s), so your page will not need to pull the compilers from the 3rd sites

Comment: I tried the method you suggested but failed:
```<html>
    <head>
        <script src="azure-storage-blob.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://rawgit.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/master/lib/typescriptServices.js"></script>
        <script src="https://rawgit.com/basarat/typescript-script/master/transpiler.js"></script>
        <script type="text/typescript" src="browsertest.ts"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```
Another question I had was: can't I just compile this file in my editor's environment so I don't need to do so in my .html file? I tried this method but failed .

Comment: try to move the `<script src="azure-storage-blob.min.js"></script>` in your `<head> ` below the  `<script src="https://rawgit.com/basarat/typescript-script/master/transpiler.js">`

In order to compile the file for stand alone usage you still would need some tool i.e. gulp/grant/webpack/babel . editor's doesn't have this functionality built in

Comment: Still nothing comes out in the console, guess that I will try to be more precise next time when asking a question, thanks a lot for your help.